# How to convert arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, integer, double

Is it possible to convert integer arraylist in java to double arraylist. For example, I have;

```
ArrayList<Integer> array  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

one example of how I am using it, is;

```
System.out.println(array.get(2));
```

but in the process of printing this out, I want to covert it into double, is it possible?

Comment: If all you're doing is accessing the members of the array, and not changing it, you can just cast when you access: println((double)array.get(2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use Java 6/7 a simple for-loop will do the trick:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>(ints.size());

for (Integer i : ints) {
    doubles.add(Double.valueOf(i));
}
```

Or, if you simply wish to print it just assign it or cast it to a `double`:

```
double d = ints.get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, you can simply:

```
double[] arr = yourList.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).toArray();
// now you can new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(arr))
```

If you work with earlier versions of Java, you can iterate on the arraylist and construct new one manually.

Comment: I am using java 1.6/7

Comment: I don't have access to java 8 at my place

Comment: @Henry You can manually iterate on it, convert each value and insert to the new `Double` arraylist.

Comment: I am updating my system, I will probably have it in another couple of months :) hopefully. ATM, I have to stick with 1.6/7

Comment: _"// now you can new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(arr))"_ Well no it'll give you a `List<double[]>`. But you don't need `mapToDouble`; if you want a `List` at the end, `List<Double> list = yourList.stream().map(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());` will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You can type cast int to double  :

```
(double)array.get(2)
```